# Set system property inside TestNG XML suite

Tags: java, parameters, testng, system-properties

I have a test suite like this:

```
<suite name="MySuite">
    <parameter name="key" value="val"/>
    <test name="testing">
        <packages>
            <package name="mypack.testpackage.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

but I need to use `key` as a **system property** instead of a **parameter** (because I use it later in some Spring ELs where I can't use `@Parameters` to take its value).

So I'd like to use something like:

```
    <system-property name="key" value="val"/>
```

or

```
    <parameter name="key" value="val" system-property="true"/>
```

instead of the parameter

```
    <parameter name="key" value="val"/>
```

Does TestNG support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't support out of the box - you will need to write code for it to override if values are available as system properties.